# BST with duplicates(RABPAB)

Tags: binary-search-tree

I wanted to create a BST for the string "RABSAB".

The rules for inserting into the tree are:

1) left subtree of a node < the node's key.
2) right subtree of a node >= the node's key.

i ended up with two answers:

```
    R                       R
   / \                     / \
  A   S                   A   S
   \                       \
    A                       B
     \                     /                 
      B                   A                    
       \                   \
        B                   B
```

Which one among them is correct?

Comment: (B) right hand side tree is correct...

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for that?

Comment: Yes I can, but before this first you explain how did you write two trees with same rules. (add in your question)

Comment: My thinking may be wrong.
For the first tree, while inserting the second A, i removed the already created node B and replaced it with A then i inserted B as per the rules.

For the second tree, while inserting the second A, i did not replace the nodes in the tree. I just went on adding them(i did not mean to rearrange it)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like

```
      R
     / \
     A  S
      \
       B
      /
     A
      \
       B
```

this way you would instead have a trie instead of a tree

Comment: The above tree is violating the basic rules itself